# How can I use _stprintf in my programs, with and without UNICODE support?

Tags: c, windows, unicode

Microsoft's <tchar.h> defines `_stprintf` as `swprintf` if `_UNICODE` is defined, and `sprintf` if not. But these functions take different arguments! In `swprintf`, the second argument is the buffer size, but `sprintf` doesn't have this.

Did somebody goof? If so, this is a big one. How can I use `_stprintf` in my programs, and have them work with and without `_UNICODE`?

Comment: In retrospect, it is better to dispense with non-unicode versions altogether. tchar.h has long outlived its usefulness.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're seeing parallel evolution here. `swprintf` is a latecomer to standard C, after it was discovered that (A) 8 bits is insufficient for text and (B) you should pass buffer sizes along with buffers. `TCHAR` is a microsoft idea to unify ASCII and Unicode APIs. They dropped the ball, missing point (B). The proper `TCHAR` solution should have been to define `_stprintf` as either `swprintf` or `snprintf`.

The solution is then to simply wrap `<tchar.h>` and do this yourself.

Answer (score 1):

> these functions take different arguments!

There are two different versions available with MS compilers. Take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybk95axf(VS.71).aspx).
This is in keeping with the ANSI standard. But I think that does not answer your question. I'll skip it for a while and rather tell you how you can have uniformity.

> have them work with and without _UNICODE?

You are better off using the 'safe string functions' as per MS recommendations. See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ce3zzk1k(VS.80).aspx). Use `_stprintf_s' and I think you will get around your problem.

> Did somebody goof?

**EDITED:** I don't think so. I don't have the Rationale handy to give you *the* answer. I'll post an update when I get my hands on something more concrete. In the meantime look at MSalters' explanation.

A curious thing is MS's C runtime **[does not](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sk54f3f5(VS.71).aspx)** claim compatibility with the ISO standard.

***Disclaimer: I am not defending the giant of Redmond, only pointing out stuff that strikes me as odd!***

Comment: No point in claiming that, as the ANSI C standard is a repackaged ISO C standard. Microsoft is not an ISO member; they're an ANSI member. (INCITS today), which in turn is an ISO member.

Comment: @MSalters: I am not defending MS, only pointing out what strikes me.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be directly answering the question, but one alternative is to use  `_stprintf_s`. You have to add the extra parm, but then it will still compile both ways, and is more future-proof.