# Problems in _stprintf /stscanf Unicode functions

Tags: c++

I work in VS 2017 with UNICODE data

And I get very strange errors,
working  with  format instructions

_vstprintf,
_stprintf.
_stscanf

I get wrong results, 
eg:
 In function

_stprintf(str,_T(“%s\t%s”),txt,nver  );

str Contains 1st character 'V' only
 and so on

What I do wrong?
Please help me!

````
    ```C++
    `static void a_txtf ((_TCHAR  *str,  
                       _TCHAR *fmt, ...)    
    {
       _TCHAR     buf[256];

       va_list   marker;

       va_start (marker, fmt);
       _vstprintf  (buf, fmt, marker); 

        // Data in buf are wrong!                                        
        // Contains 1st character only

       va_end(marker);

       int l = _tcslen (buf);
      _stprintf(str, _T("%-*s\r\n"),   
                l,buf);  


       // str is wrong! 
       // Contains 1st character only
    }

    void main ()
    { 
         _TCHAR txt[] = _T(“  VERSION ”);
         _TCHAR nver[] = _T(“  5.123 ”);
         _TCHAR line[]=_T(“ORDER1\t123”);

         _TCHAR str[256], name[32]; 
         Int num;

    a_txtf(str,_T(“ %s\t %s”),txt, nver);


    _stprintf(str,_T(“%s\t%s”),txt,nver  
                 );
         // str is wrong! 
         // Contains 1st character only

        _stscanf(line,_T(“%s%d”),name,num 
    );

         // name is wrong! 
         // Contains something like 
         // Chinese 
         //text in name
         // num is OK
    }`
````

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/594799/how-can-i-use-stprintf-in-my-programs-with-and-without-unicode-support

Comment: _stprintf seems hopeless, see link above. But there is no reason to use _T functions and strings in 2019. Decide whether you want wide characters or narrow characters and use the appropriate functions, sprintf or swprintf in your case.

Comment: Your title is wrong, _stprintf is **not** a unicode function, the unicode function is swprintf. The purpose of _stprintf is to write code that is compatible with both unicode and non-unicode. If you really want unicode then just use swprintf, your error will be obvious then.